# Angular6 json schema form loads Bootstrap module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular6-json-schema-form

I'm using [angular6-json-schema-form](https://github.com/hamzahamidi/Angular6-json-schema-form) in Angular v6 project. I installed it with command:

```
$ yarn add angular6-json-schema-form
```

I imported `Bootstrap4FrameworkModule` like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { Bootstrap4FrameworkModule } from 'angular6-json-schema-form';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
    Bootstrap4FrameworkModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And my component is like the following:

```
<json-schema-form
loadExternalAssets="true"
[schema]="schema"
(onSubmit)="submit($event)">
</json-schema-form>
```

The generated forms works fine but the `Bootstrap4` styling doesn't work. I have no styling only plain html.

Comment: may be you should add css in index.html . Read the documentation of external library to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind I found the solution in Documentation. I need to specify the `template/framwork` in the component HTML:

```
<json-schema-form
loadExternalAssets="true"
[schema]="schema"
framework="bootstrap-4"
(onSubmit)="submit($event)">
</json-schema-form>
```